# Guided Meditation for Children

Tags: sleep

My second grader has been having trouble sleeping due to her anxiety.

I have been doing guided meditation/relaxation with her at night but this is not my forte and am looking for suggestions, such as trying music or other forms of assistance.  How can I help teach my daughter some meditation techniques?

Comment: This is a very interesting question (as long as it doesn't turn into specific iTunes recommendations). I wish you a working solution!

Comment: I have made some edits to the question, to try and avoid more answers that don't address what you are actually asking.  I'm hoping that removing the background will make clear that you've decided on a solution you'd like to pursue, and that your question is specifically about that solution, rather than an invitation to suggest alternate solutions.  Please feel free to roll back my changes if you think I've strayed from your intent, though.

Comment: Beofett, based on the poster's comment that "I think therefore that this strategy is working," it might be possible that the question is more broad. Only the OP can really clarify, though.

Answer (score 1):

So I went and did some looking around online and was somewhat surprised at how many legitimate links turned up when I Googled "guided meditation, children".  Some of it might need to be modified somewhat to work for your situation.

Guided Meditation for Primary [Students](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/med-guided2.pdf). This one seems like it's specifically focused on using guided meditation in the classroom, but if some of her anxiety is coming from school, then these might be helpful for her if she starts feeling anxious while she's at school and you're not there.

Relaxation [Scripts](http://www.innerhealthstudio.com/relaxation-scripts-for-children.html) for Children

And another [script](http://www.kidsmeditationcds.net/freeguidedmeditation.htm) CDs and Mp3s are also offered here for kid's meditation and relaxation.

Comment: I don't want to be the one reading it to her, I am currently using an ipod

Answer (score 1):

**Read aloud to her.**

Your voice will calm her and take her mind off of her troubles. You will reinforce that it is time for calm and quiet, and the routine will be reassuring.

Look at [this site](http://www.trelease-on-reading.com/index.html) for reading aloud resources, including age-appropriate reading lists and anthologies.

Comment: I started with this, but she was getting attached to me being in her bed.  I did not want this nor can I maintain this as I have 3 other children.

Comment: I am sure you can figure something out ...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to encourage especially long evenings and she's dealing with anxiety, then [One with the Universe from ShambalaKids cd](http://www.kidsmeditationcds.net/kidsmeditationcds.htm) or Mp3 is excellent.  The audios help kid's with self esteem and stress relief. Kid's meditation and relaxation IS getting more popular and a great way to help our kids relax and sleep well. We use them every night.

Comment: Welcome holisticmama!